# Get file mime type in Corona/Lua?

Tags: lua, cross-platform, coronasdk, mime-types

What is the best way to find the mime type of a given file in Corona? I found this lua-mimetypes library:

https://bitbucket.org/leafstorm/lua-mimetypes/overview

This module seems fine but I am wondering if there is a simpler way of getting file mime types. Is there a better way to do this in Corona?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a very good option. Another one is to HTTP GET an online mime types database like http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/mime-types-full, then look through it to find mime type for your file type.